# chrome extension : how to display an icon in the toolbar?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've created a simple extension but the icon is not being displayed in the browser's toolbar and in fact I see many other extensions installed but not their icon in the toolbar. What element in the manifest file defines that an icon should display an icon in the toolbar?

Here is the used manifest file and this manifest does not add any icon to the toolbar

```
{
  // Extension ID: my_id
  "key": ".....my key.......",
  "name": "....any name....",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "description",
  "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "main.html"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "...."
  ]
}
```

Comment: There's no such element. The toolbar width is limited so only a few extensions are shown there while the rest of icons are inside the browser menu panel. The newly installed extensions are always shown in the toolbar initially. Regardless of the presence of `"icons"` in manifest.json an autogenerated icon is displayed either in the toolbar or in the menu panel.

Comment: Note, you can resize the extensions toolbar by dragging the right edge of the address bar.

Comment: You can also drag the icons and hide/show them through an icon's context menu.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact same problem and found this question on the top search results.  The answer I needed is in the comment by [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) on this question so in case it helps, I'm promoting it to an answer:

The icon is available by default but it may not be visible due to the toolbar width made available to icons.  You can edit this by clicking on the "puzzle piece" in the extension toolbar and then picking on the "pushpin" next to the extension you want to be made visible.

[image: image of "Extensions tooltip interface with options to enable extension icons.]

Hope this helps other people who are confused by this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the v2 but in v3 to load icon use `"icons"` in manifest remember icons object have key value pair where key define the size of icon and value is the path of the icon.

```
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-32.png",
    "32": "images/icon-32.png",
    "48": "images/icon-32.png"
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, although adding icons in manifest.json, you cannot view icon on the toolbar. Because you need a **browser action**.

You can try adding in this manifest.json;

```
"browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
```

Also, you should generated .html file and .png image

In Brief,

Chrome extension include third parts.

- Background script
- Content script
- Browser action(popup)

If you want see icon on toolbar, you should set a browser action in manifest.json

Comment: Wrong answer. An extension icon is always shown even if there's no browser_action or page_action. The OP's problem is that the icon is hidden in the browser menu panel when the toolbar width is too small, which cannot be changed via manifest.json.